# mysql i want to use connect by level oracle concept

Tags: mysql, oracle, connect-by, regexp-substr

```
SELECT COUNT(*) num
FROM   (
           SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(PWD, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) AS USERPWD
           FROM   (
                      SELECT PASSWORD || ',' || LPASS1 || ',' || LPASS2 || ',' || 
                             LPASS3 || ',' || LPASS4 || ',' || LPASS5 PWD
                      FROM   login_master
                      WHERE  LOGIN_ID = ?
                             AND STATUS IN ('Y', 'T')
                             AND APP_ID = ?
                  ) CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(PWD) -LENGTH(REPLACE(PWD, ',', ''))
                  + 1
       )
WHERE  USERPWD = ?
```

can you give suggestions to convert these code to mysql.